# Why does the two way algorithm match the left part in reverse?

Tags: algorithm, string-search

The [Two Way](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node26.html) algorithm is a substring search algorithm [(primary paper, 1.4 MB PDF)](http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/Articles-PDF/CP-1991-jacm.pdf).

It splits the search pattern *x* in two parts: *x = x<sub>l</sub> x<sub>r</sub>*, and first it tries to match *x<sub>r</sub>* against the text, and if that is successful the algorithm prescribes matching *x<sub>l</sub>* in reverse (i.e. right-to-left order).

- Why is *x<sub>l</sub>* matched from right to left?
- Can I replace this with a left-to-right comparison instead?

The reason for the question is simple: An order unspecified comparison is already available and possibly more performant, think something like an optimized `memcmp` or unrolled loop.

Comment: How would you match it from left to right when you're looking for a suffix?

Comment: You're looking for the first occurence of a substring *x* in a text, so the global search is from “left to right” (memory order), but that half of the pattern is matched starting with the rightmost byte.

Answer (score 1):

From an efficiency point of view it obviously doesn't matter.  The only other reason I can think of is:  in case of non-matching, a right-to-left attempt potentially leaves the algorithm with more information about a *partial* match.  So going RTL, if we match 2 characters in xl and then fail, we know we have a partial, contiguous match of 2 chars + xr.  If we match xl LTR and fail, we know nothing more than the xr match.